# Travis and React Native. Parallels builds for Android and ios

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, travis-ci

I'm pretty new on Travis. I have a React Native App. Actually I'm using Travis to deploy both platforms in a sequential way.
I would like to know if it is posible to build for ios and android parallel to make the travis process faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tests and docs, I found a way to achive that. This is the .travis.yml file:

```
  matrix:
  include:
    - language: objective-c
      os: osx
      xcode_workspace: '../ios/YourProject.xcworkspace'
      xcode_scheme: YourProject
      xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator9.0
      osx_image: xcode10.1
      podfile: ios/Podfile
      node_js: false
      sudo: true
      before_install:
        - echo "before_install"
      install:
        - echo "install"
      script:
        - echo "script"
    - language: android
      android:
        components:
          - tools
          - platform-tools
      sudo: true
      before_install:
        - echo "android before_install"
      install:
        - echo "android install"
      script:
        - echo "android script"
    - if: branch = master
      language: node_js
      node_js: lts/*
      install: true
      script: echo "MASTER BRANCH"
```